# Optimize huge files comparison using specified columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following details to do file comparison.

Files Details:

[image]

**Note**: Each property of file is dynamic and File2 is appended/incremental  data of File1.

Requirement:

1. I want to do comparison on File1 and File2 and store the differential data into third file **Output.txt with File2 delimiter(|) and File2 Columns(80)**. File2 is have all data of File1 plus recent appended data.
2. File1 and File2 have 2 unique columns called as ID and Date and column index of these 2 columns may differ. I want to do comparison on these 2 columns(ID,Date).
3. If I found any other character in the date column then I want to store that record in the Error.txt file.
4. Delimiters are dynamic.
5. Number of columns are dynamic.
6. Columns index are dynamic.
7. In the output file, I will get the result of differential data which is `0.2GB` of data.

**My try**: I tried with the following code but it's keep running, unable to get the result.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import dateutil.parser as dparser
from dateutil.parser import parse

file1 = 'E:\File1.txt' 
file2 = 'E:\File2.txt' 
file3 = 'E:\OUTFile.txt' 
file4 = 'E:\Errors.txt'

with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
    firstline = f1.readline()
    print('File1 Header:',firstline.strip('\n'))

file1_delimiter = raw_input('Please provide the delimiter:')

with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    firstline = f2.readline()
    print('\nFile2 Header:',firstline.strip('\n'))

file2_delimiter = raw_input('Please provide the delimiter:')

with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
    header = f1.readline()
    headerList1 = list(header.split(file1_delimiter))
    print('\n---File1, Column Index with Header---')
    for item in headerList1:
        print(headerList1.index(item),item)

    file1_header1 = input("Enter column1 number:")
    file1_header2 = input("Enter column2 number:")

with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    header = f2.readline()
    headerList = list(header.split(file2_delimiter))
    print('\n---File2, Column Index with Header---')
    for item in headerList:
        print(headerList.index(item), item)

    file2_header1 = input("Enter column1 number:")
    file2_header2 = input("Enter column2 number:")

file_1_set1 = set()
file_2_set1 = set()
file_1_set2 = set()
file_2_set2 = set()

def is_date(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open(file1, 'r') as f_1:
    lines = f_1.readlines()[1:]
    f_1_result = []
    for x in lines:
        if x.split(file2_delimiter)[file1_header2]:
            file_1_set1.add(x.split(file1_delimiter)[file1_header1].strip('\n'))
            if is_date(x.split(file2_delimiter)[file1_header2]) == True:
                file_1_set2.add(str(dparser.parse(x.split(file1_delimiter)[file1_header2].strip('\n'),fuzzy=True).date()))

with open(file2, 'r') as f_2:
    lines = f_2.readlines()[1:]
    f_2_result = []
    for x in lines:
        if x.split(file2_delimiter)[file2_header2]:
            file_2_set1.add(x.split(file2_delimiter)[file2_header1].strip('\n'))
            if is_date(x.split(file2_delimiter)[file2_header2]) == True:
                file_2_set2.add(str((dparser.parse(x.split(file2_delimiter)[file2_header2].strip('\n'),fuzzy=True).date())))

with open(file2, 'r') as in_file, open(file3, 'w') as out_file, open(file4, 'w') as err:
    out_file.write(next(in_file))
    set1_diff = (file_2_set1 - file_1_set1)
    set2_diff = (file_2_set2 - file_1_set2)

    for line in in_file:
        if line.split(file2_delimiter)[file2_header2]:
            if is_date(line.split(file2_delimiter)[file2_header2]) == True:
                if line.split(file2_delimiter)[file2_header1] in set1_diff or str(dparser.parse(line.split(file2_delimiter)[file2_header2].strip('\n'),fuzzy=True).date()) in set2_diff:
                    out_file.write(line)
            else:
                err.write(line)
```

Sample data:

File1:

```
ID^MICNO^Name^Dt^MidName^Address^Permanent Address^ASID^E-mail ID^Gender^Nationality^Subscriber Details^D No^UMO No^Type^DType^S Subscriber^CType^FormA^POU No^SSAP^CD^Date
223344^^Jak . .^^MAK^HNo 123 USA^    -^^^^^^^^^^^TM^^^^^14-04-2012
56432178^^David . .^^Koustry^HNo 366 UK^    -^^^^^Ink Olk^^^^^^TOM^^^^^23-02-2015
3241567890^^Simon . .^^Plourd^HNo 233 UAE^    -^^^^^^^^^^^TMM^^^^^28-07-2016
```

File2:

```
ID^MICNO^Name^Dt^MidName^Address^Permanent Address^ASID^E-mail ID^Gender^Nationality^Subscriber Details^D No^UMO No^Type^DType^S Subscriber^CType^FormA^POU No^SSAP^CD^Date
12334^^Brod . .^^Plaku^HNo 5400 CAN^    -^^^^^^^^^^^TM^^^^^14-04-2012
56432178^^David . .^^Koustry^HNo 366 UK^    -^^^^^Ink Olk^^^^^^TOM^^^^^23-02-2015
3241567890^^Simon . .^^Plourd^HNo 233 UAE^    -^^^^^^^^^^^TMM^^^^^28-07-2017
```

Output file should have:

```
ID^MICNO^Name^Dt^MidName^Address^Permanent Address^ASID^E-mail ID^Gender^Nationality^Subscriber Details^D No^UMO No^Type^DType^S Subscriber^CType^FormA^POU No^SSAP^CD^Date
12334^^Brod . .^^Plaku^HNo 5400 CAN^    -^^^^^^^^^^^TM^^^^^14-04-2012
3241567890^^Simon . .^^Plourd^HNo 233 UAE^    -^^^^^^^^^^^TMM^^^^^28-07-2017
```

Comment: It would be nice to explain what you have tried to do. Anyway, I am surprised that you are using two sets, one for the IDs and one for the dates. I would imagine that you want the lines for which the *pair* `(id, dat)` does not exist in the other file...

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I just want to do comparison on `ID` and `Date` and write all difference lines from File2 to Output file.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, As I mention column `ID` and `Date` positions are dynamic. So I just provided user to give the index of column `ID` and `Date` by providing column header of each files.

Comment: Do your files contain a header with column names? Are the delimiters limited to a restricter set of characters? What is the reason for not using the csv module?

Comment: If ID are the same and Date are different, should the line go to Output file?

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Yes, If ID are the same and Date is different then it should go to output file.

Comment: Show a small snippet of each file, with both matching and non matching line samples. Also include how you ran it, the output you'd expect to see for the example and what it actually produces.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Edited post with snippet of each files.

Comment: I thought file2 has a `|` delimiter?

Comment: Also, do you want the output sorted in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if it will meet your requirement because I could not test it on 3Gb files. I have slightly improved your code:

- I store full keys in a set, meaning pairs (ID, Date) from file1
- I read each file only once
- I only store one row at time in memory for both input files

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import dateutil.parser as dparser
from dateutil.parser import parse
import csv

file1 = 'E:\File1.txt' 
file2 = 'E:\File2.txt' 
file3 = 'E:\OUTFile.txt' 
file4 = 'E:\Errors.txt'

with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
    firstline = f1.readline()
    print('File1 Header:',firstline.strip('\n'))

file1_delimiter = raw_input('Please provide the delimiter:')

with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    firstline = f2.readline()
    print('\nFile2 Header:',firstline.strip('\n'))

file2_delimiter = raw_input('Please provide the delimiter:')

file_1_set = set()
file_1_set = set()

def is_date(string):
    print(string)
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    rd1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter = file1_delimiter)
    headerList1 = next(rd1)
    print('\n---File1, Column Index with Header---')
    for i, item in enumerate(headerList1):
        print(i,item)

    file1_header1 = input("Enter column1 number:")
    file1_header2 = input("Enter column2 number:")

    rd2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter = file2_delimiter)
    headerList2 = next(rd2)
    print('\n---File2, Column Index with Header---')
    for i, item in enumerate(headerList2):
        print(i, item)

    file2_header1 = input("Enter column1 number:")
    file2_header2 = input("Enter column2 number:")

    for x in rd1:
        if x[file1_header1] and is_date(x[file1_header2]):
            file_1_set.add((x[file1_header1], dparser.parse(x[file1_header2],
                            fuzzy=True).date()))

    with open(file3, 'wb') as out_file, open(file4, 'wb') as err:
        out_wr = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter = file2_delimiter)
        err_wr = csv.writer(err, delimiter = file2_delimiter)
        out_wr.writerow(headerList2)
        f_2_result = []
        for x in rd2:
            if not is_date(x[file2_header2]):
                err_wr.writerow(x)
            elif x[file2_header1] and ((x[file1_header1], dparser.parse(x[file1_header2],
                                fuzzy=True).date()) not in file_1_set):
                out_wr.writerow(x)
```

---

From your example of files, your input files do contain the field names. In that case you can just use a DictReader to directly process the field names from the first line.

And as you say that the program keeps running without any output, I propose to print one dot every n lines. For 3Gb file, one dot every 10000 lines should be an acceptable mix between too long between 2 dots and too much dots. Code becomes:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import dateutil.parser as dparser
from dateutil.parser import parse
import csv

file1 = 'E:\File1.txt' 
file2 = 'E:\File2.txt' 
file3 = 'E:\OUTFile.txt' 
file4 = 'E:\Errors.txt'

delta = 10000          # one dot on stderr at every 10000th line

with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
    firstline = f1.readline()
    print('File1 Header:',firstline.strip('\n'))

file1_delimiter = raw_input('Please provide the delimiter:')

with open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    firstline = f2.readline()
    print('\nFile2 Header:',firstline.strip('\n'))

file2_delimiter = raw_input('Please provide the delimiter:')

file_1_set = set()
file_1_set = set()

def is_date(string):
    try:
        parse(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open(file1, 'r') as f1, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    rd1 = csv.DictReader(f1, delimiter = file1_delimiter)

    if hid not in rd1.fieldnames or hdate not in rd1.fieldnames:
        raise KeyError("File1 does not contain ID and Date fields")
    rd2 = csv.DictReader(f2, delimiter = file2_delimiter)
    if hid not in rd2.fieldnames or hdate not in rd2.fieldnames:
        raise KeyError("File2 does not contain ID and Date fields")

    numlig = 0
    _ = sys.stderr.write("Processing file1:")
    for x in rd1:
        if x[hid] and is_date(x[hdate]):
            file_1_set.add((x[hid], dparser.parse(x[hdate],
                            fuzzy=True).date()))
            numlig +=1
            if numlig >= delta:
                _ = sys.stderr.write('.')
                numlig = 0

    with open(file3, 'wb') as out_file, open(file4, 'wb') as err:
        out_wr = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames = rd2.fieldnames,
                                delimiter = file2_delimiter)
        err_wr = csv.DictWriter(err, fieldnames = rd2.fieldnames,
                            delimiter = file2_delimiter)
        out_wr.writeheader()
        numlig = 0
        _ = sys.stderr.write("\nProcessing file2:")
        for x in rd2:
            if not is_date(x[hdate]):
                err_wr.writerow(x)
            elif x[hid] and ((x[hid], dparser.parse(x[hdate],
                                fuzzy=True).date()) not in file_1_set):
                out_wr.writerow(x)
            numlig += 1
            if numlig >= delta:
                _ = sys.stderr.write('.')
                numlig = 0
```

Comment: Not sure whats going on, It just printing the dates.

Comment: @MAK: the date printing is just a trace because I have not installed dateutils and still wanted to know If I could decode them. But OUTFile.txt should contain lines from File2.txt not present in File1.txt (according to the pair (ID, Date)).

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to [@Serge's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557714/2988730), but I think you can make additional improvements.

For one thing, your snippets show the date as a very consistently formatted string. Since you are only interested in comparing it for equality, there is no need to perform any (expensive) conversions on it. Especially not twice. Any improvement you can get in a multi-GB processing job should be worth the effort. Instead, I would recommend something like a simple regex or even a manual check:

```
def is_date_simple(string):
    return (len(string) == 10 and string[2] == '-' and string[5] == '-' and
            string[:2].isdigit() and string[3:5].isdigit() and
            string[6:].isdigit())
```

OR

```
import re

...

def is_date_regex(string, date_pattern=re.compile('\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d')):
    return date_pattern.fullmatch(string)
```

If the check passes, just use the date as-is.

For another, you can identify your columns of interest automatically, since their names are always `ID` and `Date`.

In terms of code elegance, I would recommend using the fact that files are iterable over their lines more directly. Do **not** use `readlines` on a huge file! That loads the whole thing into memory all at once instead of using Python's built-in buffering mechanisms.

As a nitpick, don't do `if ... == True:`. `True` is a singleton, and should be compared with `... is True`, which is much more efficient. However, if you are using an `if` statement, leave out the comparison entirely. `if ...:` is sufficient and better, because it automagically converts `...` to a `bool`.

Here is how I would construct the initial index set:

```
def initialize(file, delim):
    """
    Creates an iterator, moves it past the header and gets the indices of
    the id and date columns.

    Returns the iterator, the raw header line, the id and date column indices.
    """
    iterator = iter(file)
    header_line = next(iterator)
    header = [x.casefold() for x in header_line.split(delim)]
    index_id = header.index('id')
    index_date = header.index('date')
    return iterator, header_line, index_id, index_date

def index(line, delim, index_id, index_date):
    line = line.split(delim)
    date = line[index_date]
    if not is_date(date):   # Use one of the implementations show here.
        return None
    return line[index_id], date

delim1 = '^'
with open(file1, 'r') as f1:
    iterator, _, index_id, index_date = initialize(f1, delim1)
    key = lambda line: index(line, delim1, index_id, index_date)
    existing_set = set(filter(None, key(x) for x in iterator))  # That's it. Whole file1 indexed
```

Here, I am assuming that your lines will not contain any quoted delimiters. Your sample data indicates that this is a safe assumption. The reason for the two functions show above is that they will be very useful for getting the same information out of the second file:

```
delim2 = '|'
with open(file4, 'a') as err, open(file3, 'a') as output, open(file2, 'r') as f2:
    iterator, header, index_id, index_date = initialize(f2)
    print(header, file=output)
    for line in iterator:
        key = index(line, delim2, index_id, index_date)
        if not key:
            print(line, file=err)
        elif key not in existing_set:
            print(line, file=output)
```

If you don't want the header of `file2` repeated in the output file, remove the line `print(header, file=output)`.

Notice that I chose not to use the `csv` module for this application. While this module is very helpful when you want to parse the data in detail, it is more expensive than just calling `split` on a string. Your CSV file is extremely simple, and you are only trying to use two elements as keys. You are also trying to shave off all the overhead you can.